# Issue in REST with Jersey while array of JSON submit for POST using Jquery,

Tags: jquery, json, spring, rest, jersey

I have a Jersey implemenation of REST which provides a API from Tomcat (Server1)

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Users create(Users users) {
    return dao.create(users);
}
```

and requested is posted from a jquery client from Apache (Server2)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: rootURL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: formToJSON(),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert('user created successfully');

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('user error: ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

This jquery is actually submitting the request to server, but server/API was not able to recognize this request.Also all other request like @Formparam /@Header etc with POST /GET is working

if I use the same thing using REST client it was working, Can anybody please help me to
sort this issue for POST with type of request Object.

Comment: If it produces "application/json" shouldn't the function return a string, not a Users? Also, do you have a @Path annotation?

Comment: @EricB   Users is annotated with '@XmlRootElement' also '@Path' is added

Comment: How does the `Users` class look like? Can you show us JSON sent to the server? How does the server respond to your request?

Comment: The class Users is like this
  `@XmlRootElement
 public class Users{
 private String firstName;
 private String middleName;
 public Users(String firstName, String middleName){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.middleName = middleName  
  }
  //TODO getter and Setter
 }`
 
 The JSON is like this
 
 `{"firstName":"First Name","middleName":"Middle"}`

Comment: please update your question (posting code as comment is not very helpful). Have you checked what exactly is on the wire? What is Tomcat returning as a response? 404? 500? is something present in server log?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug the communication problems is to inspect the headers sent to the server. In order to accomplish this task, you can inspect the request in the browser using Chrome Developer Tools. Open Chrome, press F12, go to Network tab, filter by XHR and force this request to be issue. Copy all the headers and post them here.

Then, go to your test with the Jersey Client API. Enable logging adding a filter to the client:

```
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
```

Then look at the console and compare the output with the previous one from Chrome Dev Tools.